# Converting Binary Coded decimal (BCD) to ASCii in ruby

Tags: ruby

I looking for ruby code to convert BCD to Ascii.I have tried with many codes but i am not getting proper result.

Any suggestions or code samples?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have any samples that do (not really/nearly) work? What kind of results did you get that weren't proper?

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a gem for this sort of thing.

https://rubygems.org/gems/bcd

The source code is at https://github.com/dafyddcrosby/ruby_bcd

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is long dead, I just dealt with this.  Assuming you've already converted to bcd:

```
bcd_val.to_s(16)
```

This converts the bcd value to hex, but because each nibble is a digit, and all digits are between 0-9, it effectively displays as an integer string.

Note that if your bcd number is stored LSB to MSB (depending on how you converted to bcd) the number will display backwards.  At that point you can always user *str.reverse* as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too clear what do you want to do, but hope that the following can help:

```
def to_bcd(n)
  str = n.to_s
  bin = ""
  str.each_char do |c|
    bin << c.to_i.to_s(2).rjust(4,'0')
  end
  bin
end

def to_dec(bcd)
  n = ""
  (bcd.length / 4).times do |i|
    n << Integer('0b'+bcd[i*4..(i*4+3)]).to_s
  end
  n
end


result = to_bcd(120)
p result                  #=> "000100100000"
p to_dec(result)          #=> "120"
p to_dec(result).to_i.chr #=> "x"
```

If you like, you could extend the Integer and String class with the two methods above, respectively, without arguments and substituting the parameter name with self. But someone does not like the idea to extend standard classes, because it is not a clean/safe programming habit.